# JTable Renderer Slow?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

When I used a JTable custom renderer and editor  to add a jpanel to my table's cells , I notice that rendering goes slow and the jtable navigation becomes impossible when scrolling up and down..
as you will see below , my renderer class contains an object TransactionUnit (the jpanel) , and each time the getTableCellRendererComponent() is called , it passes a Transaction to the TransactionUnit panel , which will fill the fields with data of that Transaction and returns itself to the renderer..

My Renderer Class:

```
package gui.transaction;

import baseclasses.Transaction;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class RegistreRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

TransactionUnit t;
public RegistreRenderer(){
    t = new TransactionUnit(null);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean     isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    return t.getComponent((Transaction) value);
}

}
```

the method getComponent(Transaction t) returns the jpanel with data of the transaction.

My Editor Class:

```
package gui.transaction;

import baseclasses.Transaction;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class RegistreEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ItemListener {

TransactionUnit t;
public RegistreEditor(){
t = new TransactionUnit(null);
}


@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
   return null;
}



@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if(isSelected) {

        return t.getComponent((Transaction) value);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

My Table Model Class:

```
public class Model extends AbstractTableModel{


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
       return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
       return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return list.get(rowIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return TransactionUnit.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
       list.insertElementAt((Transaction) aValue, rowIndex);
       fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Registre";
    }

    public void supprimer(Transaction unit){
        list.remove(unit);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public void ajouter(Transaction unit){
        list.add(unit);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public void vider(){
        list.clear();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setList(Vector<Transaction> l){
        list = l;
    }

}
```

with list = a list of Transactions ...

so , I'm asking for help and I hope I will find it :) , I've tried many solutions just like when I used a list of panels instead of list of transactions , the jtable became smooth , but the program takes a lot of memory and I encounter memory leaks with table with > 100 rows...

Comment: Your snippets don't show what might get wrong (most probably in transactionUnit.getComponent(), best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. Furthermore, there are several thingies wrong, probably not related to the problem. a) the editor implementation is invalid (fails to notify its listeners) b) the tableModel implementation looks fishy: getClass returns TransactionUnit.class while you store Transaction c) always fire the most appropriate event on changing the model (that updated on setValue, inserted on add ...)

Comment: I've fixed the Model issues , thanks to your advices . and as you mentioned the transactionUnit.getComponent() method causes the problem , I fixed it :) , thank you very much

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) if you think it may help others.